# Probability DIE question on Bayes Theoram

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Suppose a girl throws a die. If she gets a 5 or 6, she tosses a coin three times and notes the number of heads. If she gets 1,2,3 or 4, she tosses a coin once and notes whether a head or tail is obtained. If she obtained exactly one head, what is the probability that she threw 1,2,3 or 4 with the die ?

**My Doubt?**

Let E1 be the event that the outcome on the die is 5 or 6 and E2 be the event that the outcome on the die is 1,2,3 or 4. A - exactly one head.

I am not able to understand why the probability of 4 / 6 in {1,2,3,4} not getting multiplied with the probability of exactly one head i.e 1/2 to get P (A/E2)?

Comment: $P(A | E_2)$ is *equal* to $\frac 12$. Are you saying this is not true? Or are you not sure why it is true?

Comment: I am not sure why it is True.

Comment: I hope the answer below makes it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability you mentioned is

$$P[E_2 \cap A] = P[E_2] \cdot P[A|E_2] = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right) \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{3}$$

However, the question is asking for $P[E_2|A]$, which, by Bayes' Theorem, is

$$\begin{align}
P[E_2|A] &= \frac{P[A|E_2] \cdot P[E_2]}{P[A]} \\
\\
&= \frac{P[A|E_2] \cdot P[E_2]}{P[A|E_1] \cdot P[E_1] + P[A|E_2] \cdot P[E_2] } \\
\\
&= \frac{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right) \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right) \left(\frac{3}{8}\right) + \left(\frac{2}{3}\right) \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)} \\
\\
&= \frac{8}{11}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank You.. One question. What could have the question said so that it could be the probability I mentioned?

Comment: It would have to be something like "What is the probability that she throws a 1,2,3 or 4 on the die and gets at least one head?" When the question is "If she obtained  exactly one head, what is the probability that ...." you have to take the phrase "she obtained exactly one head" as a given condition, i.e. something that has happened rather than something you have to find the probability of happening.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. I understood it now very well.